# using double quotes and if condition in excel

Tags: excel

I have cell that contains double quotes and comma and i want to check if the value of the cell has 0 or blank then i want to convert it into 0.00 so that is the basic idea of what i am trying to do here.  so here is my actual data look like:

```
A        B
001     "0",
002     "200",
003     "",
004     "320",
```

so i want to say if the cell contains this value:

```
 "0",
```

or this:

```
"",
```

then i want to change it into this:

```
"0.00",
```

this is my formula now and it does not work:

```
=if(B2=""0","0.00", , B2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape all the double quotes, and use the or function to test both cases you want:

```
=if(or(B2="""0"",",B2=""""","),"""0.00"",",B2)
```